# Selenium, Siebel and QTP

Tags: selenium, qtp, automated-tests, siebel

I am about to start work on a UI automation project for a client who is using Siebel 7.5. I have been looking around and it seems that there is not a lot of info out there on if it is possible to automate GUI tests in siebel using Selenium. The question is, **Is it possible to automate Siebel using selenium**. I hear there are two modes for Siebel, SI and HI, **what is the difference**?

On another note, i have heard that there are issues automating early versions of Siebel using HP QTP. **What are these issues and what is the best workaround**.

I realise this is more than one question, i will vote up whoever answers a component and the answer will go to the person who answers the most components

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the future I think it would serve you better to split the questions so you get an answer for each part of the question from someone who knows what they're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HI** stands for "Hi Interactivity" it is used for sites that are accessed over the [LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) most objects in an HI Siebel application are ActiveX controls.

**SI** stands for "Standard Interactivity" it is used for sites that are accessed externally and is usually pure HTML.

Starting in version 7.7 Siebel starter supplying Siebel Test Automation (STA) which provides an API for testing tools, this API is used by QTP for testing Siebel 7.7 and later. STA is relevant only for HI applications, for SI applications Siebel adds some hints to the HTML in order to help testing tools.

I don't know of specific problems with QTP testing classic (pre 7.7) Siebel applications and I don't know about Selenium at all so I hope the general information I provided is useful.

Comment: Cheers, as soon as i have 15 rep i will vote that one up. Is the API COM visible?

Comment: @TechTestDude, STA is not something you want to be dealing with yourself it's intended for the people developing testing tools not for the people creating tests. A search for "Siebel Test Automation" may shed some light. In any case since you say your client is using Siebel 7.5 it's not relevant for them. BTW you can accept an answer thus gaining 2 reputation points.

Comment: Cheers for that. Given the hazy nature of the question, you have pretty much covered all my touch points

Answer (score 2):

As said above, HI mode can have test hooks enabled but these are pretty basic and need some additional software to work with easily. Also, HI only works in IE which does not have the great Selenium recording tool.

On the other hand, SI mode is just HTML and works in Firefox, therefore should be testable with Selenium. Does require a little set-up and please bear in mind that there will be differences between the test results for SI and what the users will see in the much-more-usable HI mode - but if you can ignore the use of special applets, and avoid client-side coding, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of Ruby watir-classic and rautomation plus a bit of javascript to interact with almost all of the Siebel HI Components. The two Ruby gems use WIN32OLE API and COM, so in essence you could use any language that supports the Windows API. It's a huge effort, but pays off in the end, cause it's all open source, whereas tools like QTP and TestComplete cost a fortune.